tmux: list sessions by most recently attached
To work with a large number of projects, where each project has several work areas (editing, building, testing), it's convenient to keep 20 or more tmux sessions open. But when switching quickly between sessions, it can get difficult to remember which one is which (going only by name). This is especially problematic when there are multiple sessions in the same exact area (e.g., "test-1", "test-2"). In the interactive session list (i.e., the tmux choose-tree), is there a way to sort the sessions by most recently attached? It would also be helpful to assign a short tag to each session, which would display alongside the session name, and ideally would be very easy to change. There are plugins for other features like saving sessions across server restarts, but I haven't found anything for MRU or tagging.

Not sure what you are after, but there is a hook client-session-changed where you might be able to log some info. It's also available as a inotification in control mode (tmux -C).

(1) "In the interactive session list" -- Do you mean tmux choose-tree? Please be specific. (2) "It would also be helpful to..." -- The site works best in the "one issue per question" format. Sorting sessions by most recently attached is one issue, using and displaying a tag is another issue. I suspect the former has no interactive solution (i.e. for choose-tree, although it has non-interactive solution(s) with list-sessions); the latter probably has independent solution(s). Consider moving the extra issue to a separate question. Orthogonal questions are better than an assemblage.

Updated to be more specific about the choose-tree. Good idea about list-sessions, that looks promising with format and field session_last_attached. Might also find enough context from a buffer_sample to avoid tagging.

try
tmux new -s (session name)
tmux new -s george
tmux ls
0: 1 windows (created Thu Sep  5 08:57:05 2024) (attached)
george: 1 windows (created Thu Sep  5 08:59:40 2024) (attached)
I didn't light up 20 sessions to see what order they appeared in but on my panix shell, the first one is listed first (session 0) and then session 1 AKA george.
-C

Builtin options can sort alphabetically or by creation order. What I'm looking for is a different order, specifically, the most recently attached.
